# How to combine results of two MongoDB aggregation pipeline queries and perform another aggregation query on the combined result without using $facet?

Tags: mongodb, merge, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

My first query returns the following result, after various aggregation pipeline stages:

```
{ 
    "group" : "A",
    "count" : 6, 
    "total" : 20
},
{
    "group" : "B",
    "count" : 2,
    "total" : 50
}
```

My second query returns the following result, after various aggregation pipeline stages:

```
{
    "group": "A",
    "count": 4,
    "total": 80
},
{
    "group": "C",
    "count": 12,
    "total": 60
}
```

> Both the queries are performed on the same collection, but groups and transforms the data differently based on the pipeline stages.

> Both of my queries use different `$match` conditions, have various pipeline stages including `$facet,$unwind,$group,$project` and operators like `$map,$reduce,$zip,$subtract`...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $unwind...},
{ $match....},
{ $facet...},
...
])
```

When I use `$facet` to run my queries as parallel queries, it gives the following error (because I'm already using `$facet` in my existing queries) :

```
$facet is not allowed to be used within a $facet stage
```

Expected Output:

> I need to find the average value for each of the group.

For that, I need to combine the results of both the queries and perform queries on the combined result.

My combined stage should look like this:

```
{ 
    "group" : "A",
    "count" : 10, 
    "total" : 100 
},
{
    "group" : "B",
    "count" : 2,
    "total" : 50
},
{
    "group": "C",
    "count": 12,
    "total": 60
}
```

Expected final result with average value for each group:

```
{
    "group" : "A",
     "avg" : 10 
},
{
    "group" : "B",
    "avg" : 25
},
{
    "group": "C",
    "avg": 5
}
```

Are there any operators available in MongoDB aggregation pipeline to achieve this without modifying my existing queries?

How to achieve this use case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches to combine results including [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/),which was introduced in 4.2

But I used the following approach since I use version 4.0

Save both of the aggregation query result in a variable and then insert it into a new temporary collection:

```
var result  = db.collection.aggregate(...); //query1 here
db.temp.insert(result.toArray());

var result  = db.collection.aggregate(...); //query2 here
db.temp.insert(result.toArray());

// Find out average
db.temp.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$group",
            count: { $sum: "$count" },
            total: { $sum: "$total" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            group: "$_id",
            avg: { $divide: [ "$total", "$count" ] }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 9):

You can run your queries separately using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) and then use below transformation to `$group` combined results by `group` and calculate the average:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            first: [ { $match: { "_": true } } ], // your first query
            second: [ { $match: { "_": false } } ], // your second query
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            all: {
                $concatArrays: [ "$first", "$second" ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$all"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$all.group",
            count: { $sum: "$all.count" },
            total: { $sum: "$all.total" },
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            group: "$_id",
            count: 1,
            total: 1,
            avg: { $divide: [ "$total", "$count" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vbAXm-zZDLr)

Note: I'm using the `_` character to indicate which query the document comes from. Obviously you don't need it and you can replace `$facet` queries with your own

Comment: @ mickl As I have mentioned earlier, both of my queries are already using ```$facet```. Now when I run this, I get the following error:  ```"$facet is not allowed to be used within a $facet stage"```

Comment: @TiyaJose I must have missed that part. Sorry for that. You cannot run $facet within another $facet so it complicates given your queries are already complicated probably best way would be to calculate average in memory. Alternatively you could use `$out` to redirect the outputs of both queries to some temporary collection and then run `$group` same way as I do in my query

Comment: But I cannot copy the results of both queries into same collection using ```$out```Mongo DB deletes the previous documents and inserts the new result for each query. It is specified in the doc that ,If the collection specified by the ```$out``` operation already exists, then upon completion of the aggregation, the $out stage atomically replaces the existing collection with the new results collection. @ mickl

Comment: @TiyaJose true, I meant `$merge` which was introduced in 4.2: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/

Comment: instead of concatArrays, we can use setUnion " { "all" : { "$setUnion" : ["$first", "$second"]} }"

Comment: @MugeeshHusain be careful. According [to docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#behavior):
`$setUnion
 filters out duplicates in its result to output an array that contain only unique entries. The order of the elements in the output array is unspecified.`